# c++ exceptions and bad reading of union

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class containing union as a field. The union is of pointers to two different classes. As a second field my class contains a flag informing which type is currently stored.

```
class Item {
    std::string *title;
    bool who_am_I;
    union { Submenu *smenu; Function *call; } content;
    public:
    bool am_I_a_submenu();
    bool am_I_a_function();
    Submenu *give_me_submenu();
    Function *give_me_function();
    /*(...)*/
};
```

Now, before each usage of my "give_me" methods I urge user to check the type through the appropriate method accessing the flag, i.e. the "am_I" methods. Nevertheless I would like my library to throw appropriate exception if the user would happen to forget about it. Can I do that without checking the flag inside the "give_me" method? I ask because it would mean that in normal usage the flag is unnecessarily checked twice.

I was wondering if, which and when does c++ throw some in build exception once the conflict of types will appear causing program malfunctioning. Or maybe should I handle this case otherwise, still preferably without double checking the flag.

Comment: Don't worry about 'checking it twice': it won't matter (provided the check function is inlined) as the `who_am_I` will be in the same cache-line as the union.

Comment: It won't matter whether it's inlined or not. The cost of the check is negligible.

Comment: Did you try to, instead of using a union, make two child classes of Item and use polymorphism instead ?
By this way, you could avoid even carrying a bool, by using the polymorphism to check the type of your item.

Comment: @tsukasan You want to avoid using a bool by adding a vtable pointer?

Comment: Don't use `union`, unless you really need to save the memory and you know what are you doing.

Comment: @Sjoerd bool takes as much memory as a pointer due to memory alignment.

Comment: @rburny That's why I don't understand why "avoiding a bool" is an argument in this case! (Note: of course is polymorphism usually better than an union, but "saving memory" is not one of the arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, first of all... why do you care if the flag is checked twice? Is that **really** a serious performance bottleneck in your product that profiling has shown must be optimized? I **very** much doubt it.

But even if it is a performance bottleneck, what's more important? A *properly functioning* application that doesn't crash seems to me to be an acceptable tradeoff for a super-tiny amount of extra overhead.

But you should probably just redesign your interface(s) so that the user always knows what he has and can't make mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check what's stored inside union. If you use union, it's up to you to make sure you are always accessing the right element. Reading the wrong one is undefined behavior and will not throw exception.

I don't know what are you doing, but I would recommend you not to use `union` at all. It's an old fashioned way to save some memory and not worth the bugs it is likely to introduce. In your case, it does not save memory at all (preceeding boolean takes as much memory as a pointer would, because of memory alignment).

Answer (score 0):

By using a union you are telling the compiler that the two types are compatible. Normally converting from the two would cause a compile time issue, since there is no user-specified, nor default conversion, however since you defined it as a union there is a default conversion to both types.

I would postulate that an extra call to check a boolean is probably not too expensive in this case.